# aplication auto-deploy to WebLogic poduce "Warning"

Tags: python, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, wlst

I've prepared simple deployment script that deploy my EJB Application to WebLogic 10.3 server.
application packed as ear file.

```
 connect(username, password, "t3://" + wlHost + ":" + wlPort)
 deploy('myApp','/path/to/ear/myApp.ear',targets='ADMIN')
 startApplication('MyApp')
 exit()
```

After succsesfull deploy message I see on Deployment Web page "Warning" Notification in health column.When I try to investigate the problem My Enterprize Application -> Modules -> Myjar file ->Monitoring

I can see that jms/MyAppResponseQueue staus is disconnected (status -> initialization)

Please advice how to solve the problem
When I try to deploy my ear via WebLogic screens - everything is OK.No warnings -> application is in Active mode

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my question because I don't like to keep unanswered questions. The problem was in deployment target . I targeted ADMIN but need to target one of the cluster memebers that have jms/MyAppResponseQueue resource.